# default value for variable

Tags: python, default-value

I have a simple question :

```
country = input_data['pays']
```

I it could happen that 'pays' does not exist. Is it possible to put a default value, so  that it dont raise that error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/tmp/tmpe5kIHr/usercode.py", line 12, in the_function
>       country = input_data['pays'] KeyError: 'pays'

Comment: use `dict.get`  ex:`input_data.get('pays', "DefaultValue")`

Comment: `input_data.get('pays', 'MY_DEFAULT_VALUE')`

Comment: What do you mean by put? into the country variable or into the dictionary?